# How to show that a root of a bivariate homogeneous polynomial divides the polynomial?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, algebraic-geometry, projective-space

For univariate polynomials, one has by polynomial long division that, given any root $a$ of a univariate polynomial $Q(x)$, $(x-a)$ divides $Q$, i.e. $Q(x)=(x-a)f(x)$ for some polynomial $f(x)$.

Now, as part of the definition of **root** for a bivariate **homogeneous** polynomial in (an early draft version of) *Algebraic Geometry: A Problem Solving Approach*, it is claimed in the definition, but not shown, that, given any root $(a,b)$ of the bivariate polynomial $P(x,y)$, $(bx-ay)$ divides $P(x,y)$.

**Question:** How does one show that $$(a,b)\text{ is a root of }P(x,y) \implies P(x,y)=(bx-ay)f(x,y)?$$

**My attempt:** First, because in the text one is working with homogeneous polynomials meant to act on points of $\mathbb{CP}^1$ and later $\mathbb{CP}^2$, we can assume that at least one of $a$ and $b$ is ***not*** $0$, since there is no point corresponding to $(0,0)$ in the complex projective line.

Now basically I tried to reduce the bivariate case to the univariate case via "de-homogenizing" i.e. evaluating at a given value of $x$ or $y$. In other words, given that $(a,b)$ is a root of $P(x,y)$, it follows immediately that $a$ is a root of $P(x,b)$, so by the result for univariate polynomials, we have $$P(x,b)=(x-a)g(x,b) = (bx-ab)\frac{g(x,b)}{b} $$ assuming that $b\not=0$. Analogously, in the case that $a\not=0$, we have that $$P(a,y)= (y-b)h(a,y) = (ba-ay)\frac{-h(a,y)}{a}.$$ These results together certainly suggest that $(bx-ay)$ divides $P(x,y)$, but I am unsure about at least two things (which are probably dumb misunderstandings on my part, I apologize in advance):

**1.** How do I argue this when one of $a$ and $b$ ***is*** zero? For example, if $b=0$, and thus $bx-ay=-ay$, do I just ignore trying to show that $x-a$ divides $P(x,b)$ and focus only on showing that $y$ divides $P(a,y)$? If not, what's the workaround?

**2.** How do I show that $f(x,b)=\frac{g(x,b)}{b}$ and that $f(a,y)=\frac{-h(x,a)}{a}$? Do I need to appeal to the fact that we are working in projective space, i.e. results that differ by a non-zero multiplicative factor are equivalent in a standard sense? Or is the result that $(bx-ay)$ divides $P(x,y)$ more generally true?

Comment: I'm a little confused by this; I may have a counter example. Let $P(x,y)=x^2+y^2-1$, and we see that $(1,0)$ is a root. So the claim is that $-ay$ should divide $P$, but it doesn't.

Comment: What you are looking for is if $P$ is a *homogeneous* polynomial with a root $(a:b)\in \mathbb{P}^1$ in *projective coordinates*, then $bx-ay$ divides $P$. This is the only setup I can think of (specially since the quote come from an algebraic geometry text) that this sentence can make any sense...

Comment: I think you should emphasize (or at least mention!) the homogeneous hypothesis from the very beginning.

Comment: @Cbjork that would explain why I can't prove it -- because it's not true

Comment: @Hamed I believe paf already fixed my post before I logged in today. Also thank you for pointing this out -- I wasn't sure if this relied upon the homogeneity assumption at all or if it was true generally.

Comment: @Hoot Sorry about that, I didn't mean to mislead anyone -- I genuinely thought it was true more generally, but the consensus seems so far to be that the homogeneity hypothesis is necessary. This is what my "gut feeling" tells me, but I am not sure which assumptions I should refer to in order to justify the claim rigorously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The valuable concept in this problem is that you can reduce this to the case you already understand, univariate polynomials, by picking an appropriate affine coordinate patch on $\mathbb{P}^1$. If $\mathbb{P}^1=\operatorname{Proj} k[x,y]$, take the affine coordinate patch given by $D(x)$ if $a\neq 0$ and $D(y)$ if $b\neq 0$ (if $a,b\neq 0$, it doesn't matter which one you pick).

Without loss of generality, let's say we picked the patch $D(x)$. The affine coordinate ring of this is $k[y/x]$, and the coordinate of the point which was $(a,b)$ is now $\frac{b}{a}$. On this patch, our polynomial $P(x,y)=\sum a_i x^iy^{d-i}$ is represented by $\widetilde{P}(\frac{y}{x})=\sum a_i (\frac{y}{x})^{d-i}$ (observe this is just $\frac{1}{x^d}P(x,y)$ where $d$ is the degree of $P$). This polynomial has $\frac{b}{a}$ as a root by assumption, which means that $\sum a_i (\frac{y}{x})^{d-i}=(\frac{y}{x}-\frac{b}{a})\widetilde{Q}(\frac{y}{x})$. Multiplying through by $x^d$, we see that $$x^d\widetilde{P}(\frac{y}{x})=x(\frac{y}{x}-\frac{b}{a})x^{d-1}\widetilde{Q}(\frac{y}{x})$$

rearranging, we have

$$P(x,y)=\frac{1}{a}(ay-bx)Q(x,y)$$

and so we have the desired divisibility relation (remember, $a\neq 0$ by assumption).

Comment: Just a quick question: what are the formulas for $D(x)$ and $D(y)$? $P(x,b)$ and $P(a,y)$? And what is an affine coordinate patch? An open subset of $\mathbb{P}^1$ which is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$? The authors also use the term "affine patch" frequently as well but they never defined it.

Comment: $D(f)$ is the open set where $f$ does not vanish. For the second question: an affine patch is an open set isomorphic to an affine scheme.